# Iphone UITableView custom cell button event

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView which has custom cells as its rows. In these custom cells they have 2 buttons.

I catch the click of the button in the custom cell class. Just wondering how i pass that event from the custom cell class through to the parent view controller that is holding the UITableView control. Advice?

Thanks

Comment: I think you may be looking for something that doesn't exist like: 
UITableView *tbl = [cell tableView];
Instead as mvds suggests, just set the target of the button when you create the cell to be a selector within the table view.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    CGPoint touchPosition = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
         //do Something here
    }
}

// in cellForForAtIndexPath, bind the selector:

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the actions a UIButton performs using

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

review the `UIControl` documentation for more information. (UIButton inherits from UIControl)